# How to perform a multiplication to a floating point number represented in IEEE754

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

Given a floating point number **M** represented in IEEE754 as 
0 10000000 01010101010101010101010

How to compute the result of **Round(Mx20)** ?

I know how to translate **M** into normalized form, 
**M = 1.01010101010101010101010(base 2) x 2^1**

But I don't know how to do the multiplication **M x 20** by hand effectively, because there are so many numbers in mantissa.
any hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way forward is the standard [Long Multiplication method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LongMultiplication.html), but in base 2:

1.01010101010101010101010<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>1</sup> × 20 
= 1.01010101010101010101010<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>1</sup> × 5•4 
= 1.01010101010101010101010<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>1</sup> × 5•2<sup>2</sup>
= 1.01010101010101010101010<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>1</sup> × 101<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>2</sup>

```
    1.010101010101010101010102 • 21
                          1012 • 22
× _________________________________
    1.010101010101010101010102 • 23
   00.000000000000000000000002 • 23
  101.010101010101010101010002 • 23
+ _________________________________
  110.101010101010101010100102 • 23
```

Then we want to round the significand to 24 bits, shown in bold: **110.1010101010101010101**0010<sub>2</sub> • 2<sup>3</sup>.

So the result is 110.1010101010101010101<sub>2</sub> • 2<sup>3</sup>, or 1.1010101010101010101010010<sub>2</sub> • 2<sup>5</sup>.

Comment: I've updated it a bit, feel free to revert if you like.